# SVG / D3.js Add image in front of labels of a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a simple pie chart here:
https://jsfiddle.net/5dexn2kn/1/

Now I want to add an icon **in front of** each label, like this:
[image]

I tried to append image to each label group
https://jsfiddle.net/5dexn2kn/2/

as you can see, because `text-anchor` may be `start` or `end`, also the text length of each label is different, I don't know how to find and place the image to the correct position.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getBoundingBox()` function to achieve this.

**Code**:

```
labelG.append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://placekitten.com/20/20?.jpg')
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('width', 20)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
    return bbox.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
    return bbox.y;
  });

labelG.selectAll("text").attr("dx", 25);
```

**Complete Snippet**:

```js
const width = 400
const height = 400
const labelSpace = 50
const donutRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2
const maxRadius = donutRadius + labelSpace
const colorScheme = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)
const innerRadius = 20
const svgTranslate = [width / 2 + labelSpace * 2, height / 2 + labelSpace * 2]

function getPercent(value, total) {
  return Math.round(value / total * 100)
}

const data = [{
  label: 'aaaaaaa',
  value: 19
}, {
  label: 'bbb',
  value: 31
}, {
  label: 'c',
  value: 31
}, {
  label: 'ddddddddddd',
  value: 8
}, {
  label: 'eeee',
  value: 10
}]

const total = data.map(d => d.value).reduce((a, b) => a + b)

const svg = d3.select('#donutchart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + maxRadius)
  .attr('height', height + maxRadius)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${svgTranslate[0]}, ${svgTranslate[1]})`)

const arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(donutRadius)

const donut = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(d => d.value)

const arcG = svg.selectAll('g.arc-g')
  .data(donut(data))
  .enter()
  .append('g')

arcG.append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', d => colorScheme(d.data.label))

const labelG = arcG.append('g')
  .attr('transform', d => {
    const c = arc.centroid(d)
    const x = c[0] * 2
    const y = c[1] * 2
    return `translate(${x}, ${y})`
  })

labelG.append('text')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .html(d =>
    `${d.data.label}<tspan class="label-percent"> ${getPercent(d.data.value, total)}%</tspan>`
  )
  .attr('text-anchor', d =>
    (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ? 'end' : 'start'
  )

labelG.append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://placekitten.com/20/20?.jpg')
  .attr('height', 20)
  .attr('width', 20)
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
    return bbox.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function() {
    var bbox = this.parentNode.getBBox();
    return bbox.y;
  });

labelG.selectAll("text").attr("dx", 25);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: San Francisco Display, sans-serif;
}
.label-percent {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="donutchart"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help : https://jsfiddle.net/5dexn2kn/3/

Give the text an id :

```
labelG.append('text')
  .attr('id', function(d) {
    return d.data.label + '_text'
  })
```

This has to be unique. In this case it works but if you have the same label sometimes, it won't.

Then get the width of the corresponding label text like so :

```
var thisText = document.getElementById(d.data.label + '_text') //select based on data, as id above is given from data
var thisTextWidth = thisText.clientWidth;
```

Then use the same logic to determine if you want the text anchor to be `start` or `end` to determine the position of the image :

```
    if ((d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI) {
      return -35 - thisTextWidth;
    } else {
      return -25;
    }
```